# My friends play computer games because of me; does their use of these games count as a sin for me?

Tags: halal-haram, game

I play game called [League of Legends](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/) and because of me, two of my friends started playing it also.  I know playing games is a sin, my question is: Do I get their sins when they play it? As in, when they play alone, do I get their sins?  And when we are together, do I get them?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking the 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help]. What exactly makes you think playing games is a sin?

Answer (score 2):

Playing games is not a sin. If you play too much and you miss salah or delay it then it is a sin. If your friends are missing salah or delaying it because they are playing games then it is a sin for them and I think you will get a sin for tempting them.

Comment: I think it is very dangerous to say that you think he will get a sin for tempting them (or for making them play) even though they miss their prayers or delay them.